# Android Map API V2 : Tile Server for Overlays for Android map

Tags: android, overlay, google-maps-android-api-2

I searched and could not find an answer so I am assuming that I am the only one here who is at lost.

A newbie working on Android Maps and want to know if there is a good resource that I can use to setup a TileServer that can then be used in the Android Map.

My Aim is to have Google Maps overlaid with GeoSpatial information, in form of polygons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below code which draws the polygons on the google map based on lat long values and also manage its Hue, Aplha,Stroke width.

**PloygonDemo class**

> ```
>  public class PolygonDemoActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
>     implements OnSeekBarChangeListener {
> private static final LatLng SYDNEY = new LatLng(-33.87365, 151.20689);
> private static final int WIDTH_MAX = 50;
> private static final int HUE_MAX = 360;
> private static final int ALPHA_MAX = 255;
> private GoogleMap mMap;
> private Polygon mMutablePolygon;
> private SeekBar mColorBar;
> private SeekBar mAlphaBar;
> private SeekBar mWidthBar;
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.polygon_demo);
>     mColorBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.hueSeekBar);
>     mColorBar.setMax(HUE_MAX);
>     mColorBar.setProgress(0);
>     mAlphaBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.alphaSeekBar);
>     mAlphaBar.setMax(ALPHA_MAX);
>     mAlphaBar.setProgress(127);
>     mWidthBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.widthSeekBar);
>     mWidthBar.setMax(WIDTH_MAX);
>     mWidthBar.setProgress(10);
>     setUpMapIfNeeded();
> }
> @Override
> protected void onResume() {
>     super.onResume();
>     setUpMapIfNeeded();
> }
> private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
>     // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
>     if (mMap == null) {
>         // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
>         mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
>                 .getMap();
>         // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
>         if (mMap != null) {
>             setUpMap();
>         }
>     }
> }
> private void setUpMap() {
>     // Create a rectangle with two rectangular holes.
>     mMap.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
>             .addAll(createRectangle(new LatLng(-20, 130), 5, 5))
>             .addHole(createRectangle(new LatLng(-22, 128), 1, 1))
>             .addHole(createRectangle(new LatLng(-18, 133), 0.5, 1.5))
>             .fillColor(Color.CYAN)
>             .strokeColor(Color.BLUE)
>             .strokeWidth(5));
>     // Create an ellipse centered at Sydney.
>     PolygonOptions options = new PolygonOptions();
>     int numPoints = 400;
>     float semiHorizontalAxis = 10f;
>     float semiVerticalAxis = 5f;
>     double phase = 2 * Math.PI / numPoints;
>     for (int i = 0; i <= numPoints; i++) {
>         options.add(new LatLng(SYDNEY.latitude + semiVerticalAxis * Math.sin(i * phase),
>                 SYDNEY.longitude + semiHorizontalAxis * Math.cos(i * phase)));
>     }
>     int fillColor = Color.HSVToColor(
>             mAlphaBar.getProgress(), new float[] {mColorBar.getProgress(), 1, 1});
>     mMutablePolygon = mMap.addPolygon(options
>             .strokeWidth(mWidthBar.getProgress())
>             .strokeColor(Color.BLACK)
>             .fillColor(fillColor));
>     mColorBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
>     mAlphaBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
>     mWidthBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
>     // Move the map so that it is centered on the mutable polygon.
>     mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(SYDNEY));
> }
> /**
>  * Creates a List of LatLngs that form a rectangle with the given dimensions.
>  */
> private List<LatLng> createRectangle(LatLng center, double halfWidth, double halfHeight)              
>    {        // Note that the ordering of the points is counterclockwise (as long as the halfWidth and
>     // halfHeight are less than 90).
>     return Arrays.asList(new LatLng(center.latitude - halfHeight, center.longitude - halfWidth),
>             new LatLng(center.latitude - halfHeight, center.longitude + halfWidth),
>             new LatLng(center.latitude + halfHeight, center.longitude + halfWidth),
>             new LatLng(center.latitude + halfHeight, center.longitude - halfWidth),
>             new LatLng(center.latitude - halfHeight, center.longitude - halfWidth));
> }
> @Override
> public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
>     // Don't do anything here.
> }
> @Override
> public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
>     // Don't do anything here.
> }
> @Override
> public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
>     if (mMutablePolygon == null) {
>         return;
>     }
>     if (seekBar == mColorBar) {
>         mMutablePolygon.setFillColor(Color.HSVToColor(
>                 Color.alpha(mMutablePolygon.getFillColor()), new float[] {progress, 1, 1}));
>     } else if (seekBar == mAlphaBar) {
>         int prevColor = mMutablePolygon.getFillColor();
>         mMutablePolygon.setFillColor(Color.argb(
>                 progress, Color.red(prevColor), Color.green(prevColor),
>                 Color.blue(prevColor)));
>     } else if (seekBar == mWidthBar) {
>         mMutablePolygon.setStrokeWidth(progress);
>     }
> }
> }
> ```

**polygon_demo.xml**

> ```
>  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>           android:layout_width="match_parent"
>           android:layout_height="match_parent"
>           android:orientation="vertical">
>     <TextView
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:gravity="center_horizontal"
>             android:text="@string/properties_sydney_polygon"/>
>     <TableLayout
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:stretchColumns="1">
>       <TableRow
>               android:layout_width="match_parent"
>               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>               android:gravity="center_vertical">
>         <TextView
>           android:text="@string/fill_hue"/>
>   <SeekBar
>           android:id="@+id/hueSeekBar"/>
>     </TableRow>
>        <TableRow
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:gravity="center_vertical">
>   <TextView
>     android:text="@string/fill_alpha"/>
>   <SeekBar
>     android:id="@+id/alphaSeekBar"/>
> </TableRow>
> <TableRow
>   android:layout_width="match_parent"
>   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>   android:gravity="center_vertical">
>   <TextView
>     android:text="@string/stroke_width"/>
>   <SeekBar
>     android:id="@+id/widthSeekBar"/>
>       </TableRow>
>     </TableLayout>
>     <fragment
>             android:id="@+id/map"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="match_parent"
>             class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
>   </LinearLayout>
> ```

For more details you can check out the [Link](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/01/google-maps-android-api-v2-example-draw.html) which shows a demo implementation of drawing a polygon on map.

I hope it will help you.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. But I can not afford to draw polygons on the device. These are complex shapes, changing in representation and better processed off device. I shall still review your example. May be I will learn some thing or two.